# How to make content be on the next line if there is no space in div

Tags: html, css, vue.js

In my vue project I have component `Panel` and this code:

```js
<div class="account-container">
      <h1 class="account-header-title">Account Information</h1>
      <div class="account-container-info">
        <Panel :title="'UUID'" :text="`Your UUID: ${client.personaluuid}`" />
        <Panel :title="'Email'" :text="`Your email: ${client.email}`" :img="'email'" />
        <Panel :title="'Phone'" :text="'Your mobile phone'" :img="'phone'" />
        <Panel :title="'2FA'" :text="'Your Google Authenticator status'" :img="'google'" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Styles:

```css
.account-container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 130px;
  .account-container-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a problem, when I change page's width, I can see that those panels keep their sizes and I can scroll where I normally cannot. All I need to do, is to make that last panel be on next line, if there is no space in `div`

This looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about flex-wrap:wrap?

Comment: I am not sure you can. Most of the time at a certain breaking point, you make the whole row a column by using flexd-direction inside of a media query. If you want more control over how this will look at as a page collapses, you'll have to switch to using css grid.

Comment: Does this help you? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/